# How long can testSecret phase last in AWS secret manager?

Tags: aws-secrets-manager

I have a secret stored in secrets manager and a lambda configured to rotate the secret.

The lambda has all the required permissions to execute correctly and to set up the new password.

I want to keep the new secret in AWSPENDING for 24 hours so that services validating it have time to update.

Is that possible? It seems like a secret rotation tries a couple times and it stops, it doesn't keep on trying for long, and I don't see any parameter to configure this https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/secretsmanager/rotate-secret.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any documentation for this, but the secret rotation was tried a couple times, then went to sleep for 27 hours and resumed after that